# Creating Users Programmatically for multiple sites

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, import, programmatically, multisite

I am looking to assign imported customers programmatically to another site and store within a multisite. However, each time I attempt to manually set the website id it errors out claiming that it cannot "Call to a member function getId() on a non-object on Customer.php Line 808". First I loop through my websites, if I find a match based on the name I assign a variable the ID. Then I loop through the Stores within those sites getting the ids for them. See the code below...

```
foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
  if ($website->getName() == 'Name'){
   $websiteId = $website->getID();
  }   
    foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
        $stores = $group->getStores();
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
          if ($store->getName() == 'Name'){
            $storeId = $store->getID();
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I attempt to assign the customer to the website and store which causes the error.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer   ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($storeId)
            ->setGroup(8)
            ->setCustomerID()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");

$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();

$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

$customer   ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname('John')
            ->setLastname('Doe')
            ->setEmail('test@test.com')
            ->setPassword('yourPassWord02')
            ->setGroup(8)
            ->setCustomerID();

$customer->save();
```

I believe your issue is with `setStore($storeId)`, which should actually be an object rather than an integer.

So, perhaps:

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
```

will work for you.